# Mailchimp api v3 - replicate campaign

Tags: mailchimp

How can you replicate an existing campaign
according to v3 of the MailChimp API - programmatically? (I know you can do it via the frontend.)

https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Campaigns/Instance.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not yet possible to create or replicate campaigns in API v3.0. See the [API v3 roadmap](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/3-roadmap).

Answer (score 2):

The [replicate](https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/campaigns/#post_/campaigns/-campaign_id-/actions/replicate) API has now been implemented.